# Can I use a function to define an array's length in C?

Tags: c

For example say I have a function that returns `6`, can I use that function to define a new array like;

```
int array[funct(x)];
```

Comment: Why not try this and see?

Comment: I am literally about to enter my Finals and I dont have  no laptops around =/

Comment: Try any online compiler

Comment: I wrote code, compiled it, ran it. It prints out `func() returns 6, array size is 24`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable length arrays are valid in the C99 standard. It is possible to declare arrays inside a function the way you have described.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(void)
{
    return 6;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[func()];

    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;
    arr[2] = 2;
    arr[3] = 3;
    arr[4] = 4;
    arr[5] = 5;

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",
           arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
}
```

This compiles without any warnings, even with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

```
$ gcc text.c -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

No problems. Do go through the [Wikipedia page on variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

You could also use dynamic memory allocation if you want control over memory usage and are familiar with it. If I recall correctly, if the array size is not known at compile time, some form of dynamic memory allocation is performed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(void)
{
    return 6;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *arr;
    arr = malloc(func() * sizeof *arr);

    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;
    arr[2] = 2;
    arr[3] = 3;
    arr[4] = 4;
    arr[5] = 5;

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",
           arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);

    free(arr);
}
```

This is also valid. The output is the same.

Comment: Thank you for your time! It is a big help for me.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I found this.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html
Indeed, there is a space between `#include` and `<stdio.h>`. However, the doc does not explicitly state that a space must be included. So, what could be the reason? Why exactly does the standard ask to use space?

Comment: The space is 'not mandatory' in the sense that `#include<stdio.h>` can be tokenized accurately with or without a space between `#include` and `<stdio.h>`.  However, it is conventional to put the space there; not doing so makes your code look like it was written by a newbie who doesn't know any better.  You can also write `#include "stdio.h"` but that too looks like a newbie's code.

Answer (score 1):

Test code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int func(void) {
  return(6);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned int len = func();
  int array[len];

  printf("func() returns %u, array size is %ld bytes with %ld elements\n",
     len, sizeof(array), sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array));

  return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o dummy dummy.c
$ ./dummy 
func() returns 6, array size is 24 bytes with 6 elements
```

YMMV, though, eg.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wc90-c99-compat -o dummy dummy.cdummy.c: In function ‘main’:
dummy.c:10:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘array’ [-Wc90-c99-compat]
   int array[len];
   ^~~
$ gcc -Wall -Wc99-c11-compat -o dummy dummy.c
$
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. I apperciate that

Comment: A particular compiler accepting code without any specific language switches is not a good indication that something is allowed in C as a language.

Comment: Oh so it works? Thats good news! Thank you again, I am new to this stuff.

Comment: @AnthonyEgeKOPRİ -- it would not work in Standard C before C99, when variable length arrays were introduced. VLAs were made optional with C11, so now it _might_ work (it will probably work). But if this is for a test, you need to know the context of the question.

Comment: That's why I ended my answer with "YMMV". With my compiler (GCC 8.2.x) it works, with yours it might not.

Comment: Updated the answer to show the difference between size and elements.